# How to use slug with subdomain?

Tags: htaccess, subdomains

I've migrated a Hubspot blog to a Wordpress site but now need to use the same subdomain that was used for the Hubspot blog on the new Wordpress site.

Hubspot url: `blog.sitename.com/blog/post-name`

Wordpress url: `sitename.com/blog/post-name`

I've worked with subdomains before by masking url's with them, however in doing so, the slug is never shown... because it's been masked.

How can I get the new Wordpress site's url to read like this:

`blog.sitename.com/blog/post-name`?

Comment: Who is your host?

Comment: GoDaddy is the host.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [WP Subdomains](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-subdomains/) plugin. It allows you to use Category slug, Page slug, or Author name as the subdomain name. You’ll have to configure your webserver for each subdomain you want to use. Make sure that a DNS entry has been added to point the subdomains to your server.